# Java ResultSet.getString() for Date field displaying 00:00:00.0

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc, resultset

I am using a generic method to loop through and convert a ResultSet to a String array.  I am wondering why does the Date column in Oracle db value come print out as 2015-01-09 00:00:00.0  while the date in the database shows 2015-01-09 ?

Here is the code, the col type in Oracle is Date

```
    while(rs.next()) {
        String[] arr = new String[colCount];
        for(int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
            arr[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
        }//end for
        list.add(arr);
    }//end while
```

So that is part 1 of the question, part 2 of the question - is my best option for a generic method here to do a .replace 00:00:00.0 to remove that?

Comment: If you're accessing a `DATE` column, you should use `rs.getDate()` instead. Why would you want an implicit conversion to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `rs.getString()` on a Date datatype. You should be using `rs.getDate()` and then parse the date as you wish.

Example:

```
java.sql.Date date = rs.getDate(i);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Or you can directly get date as string directly from the database using the `TO_CHAR` function like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(col1, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS 'MYDATE' FROM TABLE1;
```

And then get it as string:

```
String dateStr = rs.getString("MYDATE");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle `DATE` datatype contains both a date and a time. So this isn't weird -- it is Oracle.

I would personally convert the date to a `java.sql.Date` to remove the trailing time. You can use the `ResultSet.getDate()` method for this.

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar)) on this.

Comment: You mean `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, I did mean java.sql.Date although that is another form of a java.util.Date, after all :) I will edit to reflect. Thanks.

Comment: That was one of the answers i was looking for (Oracle Date contains both date and time) - thanks!

Comment: Is there a better approach nowadays? For example, with Java.util ?