# SQL date format() not working in JTable while retrieving data

Tags: java, mysql

MySQL query to retrieve data in JTable from MySQL DB is failing in Java Code but **work fine in SQL Workbench**

Following query :

SELECT date_format(emp_date,'%d-%b-%Y') as emp_date,emp_name,emp_accno,emp_amt,pay_mode,e_comp,e_remark FROM emppayment";

While retrieving i need "dd-mmm-yyyy" (04-Apr-2020) format so i am using above date_format to convert as per requirement.
While executing in JTable i getting following error.

Error : **java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for DATE '20-Mar-2020' in column 1.**

```
           String dquery = "SELECT date_format(emp_date,'%d-%b-%Y') as emp_date, emp_name,emp_accno,emp_ifsc,sal_month,emp_amt,pay_mode,e_comp,e_remark FROM emppayment;   

            pst = con.prepareStatement(dquery);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();       
            DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            tm.setRowCount(0);

         while (rs.next()) {
             Object obj[]= {
            rs.getString("emp_date"),
            rs.getString("emp_name"),
            rs.getString("emp_accno"),
            rs.getString("emp_ifsc"),
            rs.getString("sal_month"),
            rs.getString("emp_amt"),
            rs.getString(pay_mode),
            rs.getString(e_comp),
            rs.getString(e_remark)};

            tm2.addRow(obj);
 }
```

Please guide me

Comment: Hi, here is the answer to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33166539/3262990

Answer (score 0):

## Data type mismatch

As to your error, I wonder if the type of the column in the data model backing your JTable specifies a date-time data type while your code is providing a `String` object. So, a data type mismatch.

## Use Java, not SQL

I would do such formatting in your Java app rather than in your SQL.

### `LocalDate`

Retrieve the value from your `DATE` column as a `LocalDate` using a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later. Such drivers are able to directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

### Localize with `DateTimeFormatter`

Automatically localize for presentation to the user.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US and so on.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

### Hard-coding a format

If you insist on hard-coding a specific format, specify your formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.UK ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks you much it worked !!!                                                                                 
          LocalDate ld=rs.getObject(1,LocalDate.class);
          DateTimeFormatter dateformat=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
          String newdateformat=dateformat.format(ld);   I coded in While loop and gave the string to object array ....Am i coded correct ?

Comment: @user13163886 You forgot to specify a `Locale` on the `DateTimeFormatter`, needed for the name of month. Re-read my Answer.

Comment: Locale Done, Sir Thank you so much .